# Returning the node before another node in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to return the node that comes before the given node in a singly-linked list. The tests that came with the assignment indicate that my implementation is wrong, but I just can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated. This is my code:

```
/* Returns a pointer to the node before node N in the list L, or returns NULL
 * if N is the first node in the list or if N is not in the list at all. */

struct node *list_prev(struct list *l, struct node *n) {
    struct node *current_node = l->head;

    if (l == NULL || n == NULL || l->head == NULL || n == l->head) return NULL;

    while (current_node->next != NULL) {

        if (current_node->next == n) {
            return current_node;
        } else {
            current_node = current_node->next;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: perhaps because you're trying to dereference `l` (in `l->head`) before you check if it's `NULL`?

Comment: logic looks ok to me. Are you sure your list is constructed correctly? Please provide a [mre]